# Get the physical address dereferencing in Kernel unaligned access oops

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded

I am facing with a kernel crash in Linux because the pppoe driver is dereferencing some bad adress. If i use this piece of code with the problematic pointer:

```
printk("this pointer points to %p\n", pointer);
```

Its printed virtual address or physical address? When i get the output of kernel crash i get the epc program counter value, is this epc value physical or logic address? I would like to know if the address falls within RAM memory scope. Furthermore, supossing my system has a bus 32-bit wide, how can i know if the address is aligned or unaligned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All those addresses shown are virtual addresses.  An aligned pointer will have zeroes in its least significant bits (for example, if it is 8-byte aligned then the 3 least significant bits will be zeroes).